# jQuery If Another Page Contains Text Then Do Something

Tags: jquery, get

I want to add a certain element to a page based on if the current user is contained on another page (in same domain). The list of users is in text on that page but I can't figure out how to search those values against the current user name and determine if it exists or not. This is what I have:

```
var thisuser = this part works;

$.get('adminlist.html', function() {
    if ($(this).find(thisuser)) {
       //do something but just alert for the sake of argument
       alert(thisuser);
    }
});
```

Using either .find() or .has() always returns true. Using .contains() doesn't work at all. Am I close or way off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var thisuser = this part works;

$.get('adminlist.html', function(data) {
    if (data.indexOf(thisuser)>-1) {
       //do something but just alert for the sake of argument
       alert(thisuser);
    }
});
```